# ¿Cómo capturar respuesta de un servlet con angularJS-http.post?

Tags: angularjs, java-ee, post, servlets

hola tengo este problema, estoy trabajando con `AngularJS` y un servlet de `Java EE`, el problema es que no logro hacer que angular capture la respuesta que envia el servlet al realizar un `POST`

**app.js**

```
    var app = angular.module( 'loginApp',['login.loginService']);
    app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'LoginService', function( $scope, LoginService ){

    $scope.invalido = false;
    $scope.cargando = false;
    $scope.mensaje  = "";

    $scope.datos = {};

    $scope.ingresar = function( datos ){
        if ( datos.usuario.length < 6) {
            $scope.invalido = true;
            $scope.mensaje  = 'Minimo es de 6 Carateres, para el usuario';
            return;
        }else if ( datos.password.length < 8) {
            $scope.invalido = true;
            $scope.mensaje  = 'Minimo es de 8 Carateres, para Password';
            return;
        }

        $scope.invalido = false;
        $scope.cargando = true;
        console.log( datos );

        LoginService.login( datos ).then( function( data ) {
            //TODO... continuar
            if ( data.err ) {
                $scope.invalido = true;
                $scope.cargando = false;
                $scope.mensaje  = data.mensaje;
            }else{
                console.log( data.mensaje+" "+"desde APP.JS" );
                //window.location = data.url;
            }
        });

    };


}]);
```

mi login **service.js.**

```
var app = angular.module('login.loginService',[]);
app.factory('LoginService', ['$http','$q', function( $http, $q ){
var self = {

        login: function( datos ){

                var d = $q.defer();

                console.log("FUE LLAMADO DESDE EL LOGIN");

               $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : 'xxx-xxx-xxx',
                header: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
                data : JSON.stringify(datos)

                }).success(function(data) {
                    console.log( data+" "+"Desde Service" );     
                    d.resolve( data );
                }).error(function( data ) {
                    console.log( data+" "+"Desde Service ERROR" );
                });
                 console.log("POST done");
                return d.promise;
        }

};

return self;


}]);
```

este es mi **servlet**.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,    HttpServletResponse    response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) parser.parse(request.getReader());

    String username = "";
    String password = "";

    if (obj.get("usuario") != null & obj.get("password") != null) {
        username = obj.get("usuario").getAsString();
        password = obj.get("password").getAsString();
    }

    System.out.println("Username :" + username);
    System.out.println("Password :" + password);

    Usuario user = new Usuario(username,password);
    ControladorUsuario cu = new ControladorUsuario();

    ModeloUsuario mu = new ModeloUsuario();
    try {
        System.out.println(mu.autenticar(username, password));
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(login_p2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {            
        if (mu.autenticar(username, password)) {
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            String responseJSON = gson.toJson(true);
            response.getWriter().write(responseJSON);                
        }else{
            //response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            System.out.println("incorrecto");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(login_p2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
```

Comment: Hola ¿De casualidad ves algún error en la consola?

Comment: Hola, no, no me muestra ningún error, de echo el post se realiza correctamente. el problema es que el servlet al enviar la respuesta no la captura angular.